# Why is the link/anchor not working?

Tags: jquery, html

I am lost!!! Hopefully someone can help. I am using jqTouch. I try to get this link to work:

```
<a href="#nana" style="position:absolute; left:70px; heigth:3px; width:200px; top:70px;">test</a>
```

But it does not work.

here ist the whole body:

```
<body>
        <div id="jqt">
            <div id="home" class="current">
                <div class="horizontal-scroll">
                    <table >
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div class="slide-container current">
                                    <h1 style="position: absolute; color:white; font-size:28px; left:60px; width:300px; top:0px;"> 1. Dezember </h1>
                                    <a href="#nana" style="position:absolute; left:70px; heigth:3px; width:200px; top:70px;">test</a>                       
                                    <img src="Bilder/Foto1@2x.jpg" width="320" higth="460" position="absolute" overflow="hidden" alt="Kuss"/>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td><div class="slide-container"><img src="Bilder/Foto2.png" width="320" higth="460" alt="Kuss"/></div></td>
                            <td><div class="slide-container"><img src="Bilder/Foto2.png" width="320" higth="480" alt="Kuss"/></div></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="nana">
             <h1>testtesttest</h1>
                <img src="Bilder/Foto1@2x.jpg" width="320" higth="460" position="absolute" overflow="hidden" alt="Kuss"/>
            </div>

        </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Got it: I had to add a class="slide". Thanks Tom

Comment: please post your solution as an answer and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with this code.. Try to add This CSS property to your Link

```
z-index:10;
```

This may fix it.